# How to use Date function in LINQ to entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My method should return a list of user Notes so I did it like this:

```
  var saturday = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
  var query = from note in userNotes
  where note.NoteDate > lastMonth && note.NoteDate.DayOfWeek != saturday
        select note;
```

But i get this error:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties.

Any ideas of how can I compare day of week using linq?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx) static method. It will be transformed into `DATEPART` TSQL function call.

```
var saturday = (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday;
var query = from note in userNotes
            where note.NoteDate > lastMonth && SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", note.NoteDate) != saturday
            select note;
```

Comment: For EF, you need `EntityFunctions`.

Comment: @SLaks MSDN description of [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) class: *Provides common language runtime (CLR) methods that call functions in the database in **LINQ to Entities** queries.*

Comment: A little warning that the result of `DatePart` is dependent on the "first weekday setting" in SQL Server and an alternative approach is here: http://c-sharp-snippets.blogspot.de/2011/12/getting-dayofweek-in-linq-to-entities.html

Comment: @Slauma +1 for the interesting solution in introduced link

Comment: @Alireza: Yes, it's a good solution, not only because it circumvents the dependency on the "first weekday setting" but also because it uses only `EntityFunctions` which is provider/database independent while `SqlFunctions` will only work with SQLClient/SQL Server (except that one possibly has to choose another (maybe later) reference year than 1753 to support other databases equally well).

Answer (score 3):

As I'm using Oracle, I couldn't use `SqlFunctions` class. Eventually I found a simple workaround for this problem:

> Typically when you attempt to use a property that LINQ doesn't
>   natively support, you'll need to create a concrete implementation of
>   the collection before applying your LINQ constraints.
>
> You can do this using the ToList() or AsEnumerable() methods prior to
>   your Where clause as seen below :

```
 //Using the ToList() method
IEnumerable<CalendarDate> LessonDates = db.CalendarDates.ToList().Where(cd => cd.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday);

//Using the AsEnumerable() method
IEnumerable<CalendarDate> LessonDates = db.CalendarDates.AsEnumerable().Where(cd => cd.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday);
```

SOURCE: [link](http://forums.asp.net/post/5562967.aspx)